# Start something when Listview is filled

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` which displays images from my cloud.
There may be a delay between when my user open the `activity` with the `ListView` and when the `ListView` is populated with the images.

For example if the user do not have the Internet connection on, the images won't be displayed.

I'd like to change several things on my `UI` (add a button, start an animation...) only when the `ListView` is filled. I guess I should use a listener to know when the L`istView` is not empty or when my `EmptyView` visibility is gone. Here are the two solutions I tried :

Solution 1:

```
       myListview.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int i) {
                if (myListview.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
//UI changes here
```

Solution 2 :

```
if (listviewAdapter != null){
...UI changes here
```

None of these solutions work, and I cannot find another one. Any idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: just get listViewAdapter items count. if(listViewAdapter.getItemsCount > 0) do somthing

Comment: are you using some library for loading images? how are you fetching image from cloud?

Comment: then you can use glide listener to check when image is loaded.

Comment: @junaidhafeez thank you that's what I'm using. I still have a few issues but Im on the good way :)

Comment: great. happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timer for this approach. For example wait for 5 seconds or 10 seconds and check if the listView is populated or not if yes then show what ever you want else do not show.

```
 final Timer timer2 = new Timer();
            timer2.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {

                   if(listViewCount>0)
                   {
                       //do your stuff
                    }

                }
            }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use AsyncTask class like this:**

```
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
...
if(checkConnexion()){ showToast("No Connexion"); }
else{ new loadImage().execute(); }
}
class loadImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
ProgressDialog   dialog;
  @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    /* show ProgressDialog before doing anything*/
       dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getApplicationContext(), "Veuillez patienter", "Chargement des données....", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... param) {
        try {
    /* load your images into ArrayList for example */
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        return null;
    }
     @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void res) {
/*    ** Update your UI here ***
if size of ArrayList >0 initial your adapter
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    else showToast("Erreur loading ..."); 
 ****hide ProgressDialog after finishing***  */
dialog.dismiss();
}}
private void showToast(String msg){Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
```